# Cut and paste data to a new sheet based on List

Tags: list, copy, row, paste

So I've found the below code which is perfect for what I want to do but instead of just deleting the rows I want to change the code to either copy and paste to a different sheet (Blocked Holidays), and then delete (or just cut and paste). The doc has 290k rows so which ever is less taxing on calculation time. This will be ran multiple times with a changing list of what's blocked so I need the data to be added to the end of Blocked Holidays.

This was the original question and working code:

I have two tabs in my spreadsheets (Report and Holidays). In column A of Holidays tab there is a list of dates (updated manually) which I want to exclude from Report tab (column E contains dates).

I have found a code which does what is needed but takes some time when the number of rows is around 100-200k:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub RemoveHolidaysFromReportFilterUnion()
    Const WS_NAME = "Report"
    Dim wsH As Worksheet:   Set wsH = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Holidays")
    Dim wsR As Worksheet:   Set wsR = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(WS_NAME)

    Dim del As Range, wsNew As Worksheet

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set del = GetRowsToDelete(wsH, wsR)
    If del.Cells.Count > 1 Then
        del.EntireRow.Hidden = True
        Set wsNew = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add(After:=wsR)
        wsR.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Copy
        With wsNew.Cells(1)
            .PasteSpecial xlPasteColumnWidths
            .PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
            .Select
        End With
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        wsR.Delete
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        wsNew.Name = WS_NAME
    End If
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub`


`Private Function GetRowsToDelete(ByRef wsH As Worksheet, ByRef wsR As Worksheet) As Range
    Const HOLIDAYS_COL = "A"
    Const REPORT_COL = "E"
    Dim arr As Variant, i As Long, itm As Variant

    ReDim arr(1 To wsH.UsedRange.Rows.Count - 1)
    i = 1
    For Each itm In wsH.UsedRange.Columns(HOLIDAYS_COL).Offset(1).Cells
        If Len(itm) > 0 Then
            arr(i) = itm.Text   'Create AutoFilter Array (dates as strings)
            i = i + 1
        End If
    Next

    Dim ur As Range, del As Range, lr As Long, fc As Range

    With wsR.UsedRange
        Set ur = .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, 1).Offset(1)
        Set del = wsR.Cells(.Rows.Count + 1, REPORT_COL)
    End With

    lr = wsR.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    Set fc = wsR.Range(wsR.Cells(1, REPORT_COL), wsR.Cells(lr, REPORT_COL))
    fc.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=arr, Operator:=xlFilterValues
    If fc.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells.Count > 1 Then
        Set del = Union(del, ur.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible))
    End If
    fc.AutoFilter
    Set GetRowsToDelete = del
End Function`
```